# HockeyApp Event Metrics

Tags: xamarin.forms, hockeyapp

How do I get more specific metrics from HockeyApp using Xamarin Forms? I am looking for performance metrics. I have a "LaunchEvent" event in my code that transmits time data to HockeyApp. I am only able to see how many times the event has fired and not the time data I am seeking.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can only see the event properties and metrics in Application Insights, see here regarding HockeyApp Bridge App:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/access-hockeyapp-data-in-ai-with-hockeyapp-bridge-app/